# How to load a library from vendor folder symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, composer-php

I have downloaded a library with composer. Now I want to require that file from vendor directory in my controller. So how do I require that file.

To be more specific I want to require this library
https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Comment: You don't. You `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`, and let composer's autoloader do the rest. You just include the necessary `use`statements in your code.

Comment: It is documented a very straightforwardly in the same link you provided!!!

Comment: @yivi, and what if you did not used composer and just extracted a zip?

Comment: @Black Then it depends on the library. Some libraries provide their own autoloader, some don't. The one that the OP mentioned doesn't include an autoloader, but it consists of only one class, so including/requiring that file would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once composer is done downloading your libraries it generates the autoload namespaces for your app.

To check what the generated autoload namespace for a library will be just look at its composer.json file.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": ["OpenIDConnectClient.php"]
}
```

and the generated autoload map will be in `vendor/composer/autload_psr4.php`

Here is the relevant part for your library.

Then open `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces` and check what is the actual namespace generated by composer.

when composer.json has the 'classmap' key it basically means that you will access the librabry via '\LibraryName.phar' for example.

When it has the 'psr-4' key it means that you will access your library from the namespace specified there

Example:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "Blast\\BaseEntitiesBundle\\": ""
     }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `require "vendor/autoload.php"` all packages namespaces will be available for you to use any where.

Comment: What if you only want to use specific ones instead of importing everything in vendor?